# Difference in expected predicted values from lm in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, predict

I'm struggling with a problem in R.

This list contains data of pregnant women, birthweight and parity.

I want to predict the difference in the weight gain of two future women giving birth for the first time (parity 0) to respectively a child of 3200 g and 3700 g.

I have this data set:

```
str(birth_all)
'data.frame':   910 obs. of  13 variables:
$ birthweight: int  3270 3580 3030 2460 3400 4250 4260 3450 3880 3600 ...
$ parity     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 ...
$ weightgain : num  17.9 15.9 10.4 11.5 11.6 ...
```

I can do like this:

```
bweight<-birth_all$birthweight[birth_all$parity==0]
wgain<-birth_all$weightgain[birth_all$parity==0]
P1<-data.frame(bweight=c(3200,3700))
pred_val<-predict(lm(wgain~bweight),newdata = P1,interval = "confidence")
pred_val
       fit      lwr      upr
1 15.36842 14.62545 16.11138
2 16.71779 16.07556 17.36002
```

The easy calculation will be this:

```
    pred_val[2,1]-pred_val[1,1]
[1] 1.349368
```

I don't think this solution is very elegant, and I loose the confidence intervals.

Alternatively I could use the multcomp-package, but I get similar results. Can anybody help me with a better solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've just edited to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the intervals would be doing the regression with differences:

```
bweighti=bweight-3200
wgaini=wgain-pred_val[1,1]
P1i<-data.frame(bweighti=c(3700-3200))
pred_vali<-predict(lm(wgaini~bweighti),newdata = P1i,interval = "confidence")
pred_vali
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert. That is also the solution I finally arrived at. It solves the problem.